# Multistore switcher not visible

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, multistore, switcher

I took over [this webshop](https://www.gezondenotenkopen.nl). They made a store switcher themselves. You can see the select list in action in the header. I want to add the default store switcher from `/app/design/frontend/default/trendy-green/template/page/switch/stores.phtml`.

- Its listed in `/app/design/frontend/default/trendy-green/layout/page.xml` like:

  ```
      <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
          <label>Page Footer</label>
          <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
      </block>
      <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
      <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
  </block>
  ```
- I already tried to load the default theme but no result...

Why the default store switcher isn't showing up?

Answer (score 0):

"Store" switcher that appear in default theme is actually built for switching Store Views (Languages)

it's included in layout as

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

and in header.phtml as

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
```

To make it visible - make sure that you have several Store Views in your current store and all of them are Enabled.

And to make Store Switcher available, insert next line in `page.xml` of your theme

```
  <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

near `store_language` block and use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
```

in `header.phtml`

Comment: No i don't need `store_language`. I only need `store_switcher`. To switch between the different stores and continue shopping in the card. In header or footer (I tested both) I have `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher'); ?> `

Comment: and can you provide part of layout/page.xml (as it's invisible in your first post) ?  + did you checked if several stores are enabled and linked to one website?

Comment: I update my question. Yes now in header there is the other store switcher. You can switch between stores with this select list.

Comment: ok. in my store Store switched didn't appeared by default too. But you can try to comment first and last lines  in stores.phtml - 
<?php // if(count($this->getGroups())>1): ?>   <?php //endif; ?>
and maybe it will help

Comment: + please check if each store on your website have active Store View

Comment: Ok I comment-out that code. Have a [look in footer](https://www.gezondenotenkopen.nl/). Now its loading but you can't choose any other shops...

Comment: Please see modified code for store switcher below

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just replace code of store_switcher.phtml with next

```
<?php
/**
 * Store switcher template
 *
 * @see Mage_Core_Block_Store_Switcher
 */
?>
<div class="store-switcher">
    <label for="select-store"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-store" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Store') ?>" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($store->getStoreId()==$this->getCurrentGroupId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $store->getBaseUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($store->getName()) ?> <?php echo $store->getBaseUrl() ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

and then you'll have all stores in switcher

Comment: Thanks. Then all stores are visible so that works, but I can't continue shopping in the other shops and add products and go to checkout (merge shopping card). Is this possible with the default store switcher?